`nsenter` `--root`: symlink vs. regular dir path
I am noticing a weird behavior for nsenter which I am looking some explanation for.
When I enter the namespaces of another process created with unshare I observe the differences in resulting behavior between cases where I specify root directory as a regular path vs. using /proc/PID/root symlink.
Here is the sample setup.

Prepare target process
sudo unshare --mount --mount-proc --pid --fork --root /tmp/jail bash

/tmp/jail has a linux distributive inside (I prepare it via docker export using ubuntu image):
$ docker run ubuntu
 (grab the container ID)
$ docker export 8c67e1fb5443 > ubuntu.tar
$ mkdir /tmp/jail && cd /tmp/jail && tar -xf ~/ubuntu.tar


From another terminal try entering the namespaces of that process
sudo nsenter --target=28716 --root=/tmp/jail --all bash


Try ps command
Here I observe the error:
root@ubuntu:/proc# ps
Error, do this: mount -t proc proc /proc

root@ubuntu:/proc# mount
mount: failed to read mtab: No such file or directory



If I however specify --root=/proc/28716/root for nsenter it suddenly starts working.
$ sudo readlink /proc/28716/root
/tmp/jail

$ sudo nsenter --target=28716 --root=/proc/28716/root --all bash

root@ubuntu:.# ps aux
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root           1  0.0  0.0   4624  3712 ?        S+   21:04   0:00 bash
root          31  0.0  0.0   4624  3712 ?        S    21:10   0:00 bash
root          39  0.0  0.0   7060  2944 ?        R+   21:10   0:00 ps aux

root@ubuntu:.# mount
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)

What are the reasons for this behavior? Why symlink vs. regular path makes a difference given they point to the same directory?
$ sudo nsenter --target=28716 --root=/proc/28716/root --all bash  # WORKS GOOD
$ sudo nsenter --target=28716 --root=/tmp/jail --all bash         # DOES NOT WORK GOOD

 (where /proc/28716/root is symlink to /tmp/jail)

Neither strace nor source code of nsenter seem to suggest the explanation for these differences.
6.8.0-49-generic
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS


Sidenote, /proc/pid/root is the default value for --root. From the nsenter(1) man pages: "If no directory is specified, set the root directory to the root directory of the target process" (i.e. /proc/pid/root). So, there is no need to use --root=/proc/pid/root, just --root should work.

thanks @user202311, it does not address the core of the question though

Not sure if this helps: "If directory is specified, ... the specified directory is open before it switches to the requested namespaces."

@user202311 no, I don't think it answers as well

This behavior seems to be explicitly documented in the proc_pid_root(5) man page, which says:

Note however that this file is not merely a symbolic link. It provides the same view of the filesystem (including namespaces and the set of per-process mounts) as the process itself.

